# angular-loading-bar not working unless explicit call for start()

Tags: angularjs, progress-bar, loading

I try to use `angular-loading-bar` in a simple example:

**app.js**

```
(function(){
angular.module('RoutedApp',['ngRoute','angular-loading-bar', 'ngAnimate'])
.config(function(cfpLoadingBarProvider) {
cfpLoadingBarProvider.includeSpinner = true;
}); 
})();
```

**page controller**

```
(function(){
angular.module('RoutedApp')
.controller('Page1Controller', function($http, cfpLoadingBar){
    var self = this;
    //cfpLoadingBar.start();
    $http.get('js/controllers/page1/data.json').then(function(result) {
        //cfpLoadingBar.complete();
        self.p1 = result
    });
});
})();
```

As you can see it's a simple `$http` call for a json - so  normally it should show the progress bar(I've followed code execution in angular-loading-bar.js file and it intercept the ajax call but not starting the `_show()` function); If I explicit call `cfpLoadingBar.start()` then on success `cfpLoadingBar.complete();` it works as intented.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: try a request on external data or a request that takes time to load. For example: https://randomuser.me/api/

Comment: Looks like it's working like this

Comment: In my real app i have a json ~ 12 kb size, and automatically it's not showing anything, and if I explicit call it it only show for the first time it's loading - then not showing again(I disable caching for get request - same result)